# Can I use Atom's built-in node.js server for other tasks?

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

Atom text-editor installed node.js on my machine. Now, I am just wondering, is it possible/smart/safe to use this already built-in node.js server for other tasks, as a local node.js server, or is it better to create a separate installation for that purpose?

Comment: Better to create a separate installation.  Atom will be a particular node version.  You will want to control our own version of node that you are developing with.  Besides, it's just a relatively modest amount of disk space in order to have independent control of the two projects.

Comment: Imagine you code your own server using the existing version.  Now you want to upgrade Atom.  It forces an update to node.exe, but that breaks your server.  Bad situation.  The two should be independent.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this.